# Itemize in longtable - the text and the list isn't on the same level

Tags: longtable, itemize

Good morning

I have one problem. I have in `longtable` one `itemize` list, look below. The problem is they aren't on the same level, picture below. The list is a bit downer than text on the left side.

Thanks for help.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm,     bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm,showframe]{geometry}
%showframe
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}


\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy

    \begin{longtable}{llp{3cm}}
      \toprule
      {\sffamily some text}   & \textsl{some text}  & \begin{itemize}
                                                        \item[-] some text
                                                        \item[-] some text
                                                        \item[-] some text
                                                    \end{itemize}\\
      {\sffamily some text}   & \textsl{some text}  & some text\\
      \toprule  
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would add pacage `enumitem` and modify the topsep. And probably also set `noitemsep`. Or `nosep`.

Comment: No. No change. I've tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a negative space.

```
\documentclass[10pt,%a6paper%unused
]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm,     bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm,showframe]{geometry}
%showframe
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{llp{3cm}}
    \toprule
    {\sffamily some text}   & \textsl{some text}  \clap{\rule{8cm}{.4pt}}
    &\setlist{nosep,topsep=0sp,label=--}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
     \begin{itemize}
        \item some text
        \item some text
        \item some text
    \end{itemize}\\
    {\sffamily some text}   & \textsl{some text}  & some text\\
    \toprule  
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```